# Weblogic redirecting https to http

Tags: redirect, weblogic

I have a web app which is deployed in weblogic and can be accessed using `https://host:port/appname/index.jsp`. When a user accesses this, first a 3rd party auth page would appear and after validating the user, redirects to above url. This works fine. Similarly if someone is accessing the app using `https://host:port/appname/` after authentication he gets redirected properly

However if I access the url `https://host:port/appname` (notice there is no trailing / at the end), weblogic redirects to the http protocol, i.e. http://host:port/appname which apparently fails to load.

I can confirm the redirection using weblogic's access logs. Any idea why is this happening? I am using Weblogic 12.2.1.3. Note that I do not have any entry for welcome-file-list in web.xml(If I am not wrong, index.jsp is one of the default welcome file in weblogic).

Comment: Do you have any http server in front of WebLogic ? Can you post your web.xml file plz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requests to a WebLogic Server (WLS) usually go through a web server or a load balancer which serve as a proxy for the client requests. When the WLS requests are "front-ended" by either a web server or a load-balancer, the requests are handled via a plugin. It is important for WLS to be aware of the proxy so as to handle the request correctly. Informing the Weblogic Server of the proxy, and therefore the presence of the plugin, is achieved using the WLS setting “WebLogic plugin Enabled.”

http://www.ateam-oracle.com/wls-plugin-enabled

Try this:
`Login to WLS Console
In the Environment tab, click 'Servers'
Click on 'Servers' -> '<SSL_Managed_Server>' -> 'General' -> 'Advanced'
    - You may also set this on a Cluster level
Check the checkbox or option with the text 'WebLogic Plug-In Enabled'
    - This is minimally required
Check the checkbox with the text 'Client Cert Proxy Enabled'
    - This is only required if also using two-way ssl, client certificates
Save the changes and restart WebLogic Server`

Comment: Thanks, enabling 'WebLogic Plug-In Enabled' solved this.